# The use of "that" in a noun clause

Tags: nouns

Consider the sentence:

> The reason I didn't make it on time is that my car broke down.

Should I add ***that*** after "The reason"?

> The reason ***that*** I didn't make it on time is ***that*** my car broke down.

Is it correct to use two "that" in this sentence?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's fine to use two *that* or two of any word in a sentence as long as each is doing its own job correctly in that sentence.

It can be a bit tiring to have a lot of repetition of less common words, but while such cases might not be **good** they are still **correct**. This is nowhere near as much of a concern with small common conjunctions and pronouns like *that*. Repetition alone is not a reason to cut.

When used as a relative pronoun as here it can be omitted (this is also true when *that* is used as a conjunction introducing a subordinate clause). It's largely a matter of style. (I personally find myself writing them a lot, but preferring to cut them out if I edit, but then I personally prefer to rephrase "the reason that …" to "… because …" most of the time; there's no reason to follow my style).